# robots.txt error display when search in google

Tags: google-search-console

when i search in google for `site:domainname` and then enter it gives

> A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt

so now what will do next.

my robots.txt file structure like

```
User-agent: * 
Allow: / 
Disallow: /wp-admin/
```

Answer (score 0):

The robots.txt file looks perfect, I think the file must have screwed up in the past.
Try going to Google webmasters and submitting the robots.txt file again and let me know what's the error there?
I think it should be up and running in a few day's time - give Google some time to update :)

Cheers!